# Indexing issue in Google search console

Tags: blogger, google-search-console

I have a blogger website account.i added a new post yesterday and I want to get indexing in Google search console for that new post.during live url testing page not found error is coming

My new post link

https://theveggiefoods.blogspot.com/poha-upma-avalakki